# Add product tags or terms programmatically in WooCommerce but keep the existing ones

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories

I've been reading about this functionality that I'd like to implement on my WooCommerce. The idea is that once a product is sold out, a new category "Sold Out" is automatically assigned to it.

Luckily, I've come across [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62189045/11987538). I added this piece of code:

```php
function action_woocommerce_no_stock( $wc_get_product ) {
    $term_ids = array(769);
    $tag_ids = array(770);

    // Set category ids
    $wc_get_product->set_category_ids( $term_ids );

    // Product set tag ids
    $wc_get_product->set_tag_ids( $tag_ids );

    // Save
    $wc_get_product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock', 'action_woocommerce_no_stock', 10, 1 );
```

To my functions.php and it works! the problem is that it overwrites all previous categories.

If anyone can guide me how to obtain the previous "product_cat" array and add them with the "Sold Out" category (769) I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `get_category_ids()` OR `get_tag_ids()` and then `array_merge()`

So you get:

```php
// Get product via product ID
$product = wc_get_product( 30 );

// Add this new term IDs
$term_ids = array( 15, 30 );

// Get existing category IDs
$category_ids = $product->get_category_ids();   

// Set category IDs
$product->set_category_ids( array_merge( $term_ids, $category_ids ) );

// Save
$product->save();
```

---

**Note:** in your case `$wc_get_product` is equal to `$product`